# Running out of memory while reindexing using -d memory_limit=3G

Tags: magento2, php, composer

I recently migrated data from Magento 1.8.1 to Magento 2.1.7, which includes around 700,000 customers.

After migration, I am running this command:

```
php -d memory_limit=3G bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

But I am still getting a memory error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 3221225472 bytes exhausted
(tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /<doc-root>/vendor/magento/zendframework1/
library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors
for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

I have set `memory_limit` in `php.ini` to 3 GB. I can confirm that:

```
$ php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
3G
```

I am using SSD so cannot create SWAP as per the instruction in the link above.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: try with more memory like this: `php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the server's memory from 4GB to 8GB, then assigning 7GB for PHP fixed the issue, Magento was able to re-index the customer grid in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions could be

- to set PHP > memory_limit = -1
- in data migration tool > config.xml  = 1000 or 500